# How to access listbox items in asp.net code behind which I added through jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, listbox

I'm working on a project and presently I'm doing a module that belongs to a posting article page. In this page we have a option to add keywords by using textbox and button.

I done this by using jQuery to add textbox enter keyword to listbox successfully.

If a user wants to remove any specific keyword after adding it the to listbox the user can remove it by selecting that keyword in the listbox then a remove button appears. If the user click that remove button keyword removed from listbox.

**Problem**:

After adding keyword successfully to listbox by using jQuery but I can't access that listbox items in C# code behind

Asp.net page Listbox:

```
<a id="arkyw" href="#/"><font color="#cc0000">Remove Keyword</font></a>
<span id="spKeyword" style="color:#e74c3c;"></span>    
<asp:ListBox ID="listBoxKeywords" runat="server" CssClass="list-group" style="border:0px; overflow-y:hidden; height:83px; width:300px;">
```

jQuery:

```
var count = [];
    var i = 0;
    $("#btnAddKeyword").click(function () {        
        var txt = $("#txtkeyword").val();
        $('[id$=listBoxKeywords]').show();
        if (jQuery.inArray(txt, count) != "-1") {
            $("#spKeyword").text('Keyword alread exists');
        } else {
            var listCount = $('[id$=listBoxKeywords] option').length;
            if (listCount <= 4) {
                count[listCount] = txt;
                var alreadyExist = false;
                $('[id$=listBoxKeywords] option').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == txt) {
                        $("#spKeyword").text('Keyword alread exists');
                        alreadyExist = true;
                        return;
                    }
                });
                if (!alreadyExist) {
                    $('[id$=listBoxKeywords]').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', count[listCount]).text(txt));
                }
            } else {
                $("#spKeyword").text('5 Keyword limit exceed');
            }
        }
    });
    //Remove Value from the List
    $('[id$=listBoxKeywords]').click(function (e) {        
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.is('option')) {
            $("#arkyw").show();            
        }
    });
    $("#arkyw").click(function () {
        var a = $('[id$=listBoxKeywords] option:selected').val();
        var id = $('[id$=listBoxKeywords] option').length;
        //alert('ListCount : ' + a);
        //alert('Total List Item : ' + id);
        //alert('After Remove : ' + count[a-1]);
        count = jQuery.grep(count, function (e) {
            $('[id$=listBoxKeywords] option:selected').remove();
            return e != a;

        });        
    });
```

How to access listbox items in C# code behind?

Comment: `<asp:ListBox` is web forms, not MVC

Answer (score 0):

You have not access client side data in server side.

Your client side data cleared on Postback.

The items in ListBox, Added to in client side and browser level.

You can use Json or Hidden Field to save your client side data to your Database.
Similar subject:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28379748/Creating-rows-dynamically-on-client-side-and-saving-them-to-database-on-server-side.html

You can add your listbox item data to string variable and save it to Hidden field.
For example you have 3 items:

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

When any item added in client side, Create string look like this:

,Item 1,

So finally you have this string:

,Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,

Save it to hidden field and read your hidden field in server side and split your string and then Save each string to Database and read it from server side codes.